# How to make where statement check variable value sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to create a query that selects a specific product according to the input from a user. So the users enters a product code into an entry box. and the table resulting from that query should be all rows from main table where product code = the entry from the user

I've already tried to put it in the where statement directly and it says no such column and I've tried the code below and it also led to an error

The main table's name is StoringTF 
the value of the entry box is Final_Value.

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?" 
(int(Final_Value)))
```

When I try this it gives me this error

```
File "Store.py", line 38, in submit
c.execute("SELECT * FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?" 
(int(Final_Value))
)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I expect the output to be a table but it gives me the error above

I'm really stuck in here so please help I really cannot proceed in the project I'm doing without this.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also missing a comma in the values: `(int(Final_Value),)`

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not so experienced. What should the line look like after that editing ?

Comment: See the added comma?

Comment: Gives me the same error in the answer below.
c.execute("SELECT * FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?", (Final_Value)) ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: If that's what your using, you're still missing the comma that makes the second arg a tuple. Your original code was missing **two** commas.

Comment: I'm sorry for bothering but it gives me this.
     File "Store.py", line 38, in submit
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?", 
    (Final_Value),)
    ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: Now you have a comma in the wrong place. Refer to my original comment, or the many examples in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: I've got a solution to this. I turned the var into a tuple first then I put it in with one comma before and it worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma.

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?", (int(Final_Value))
#                                                         ^ here
```

Comment: When I try it it gives me an error
    
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM StoringTF WHERE Product_Code = ?", 
    (Final_Value))
    ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: Are you sure the Product_Code column in the table is of a numerical type?

Comment: However, When I try print(type(Final_Value)) it returns <class 'int'>

Comment: Product_Code column is INTEGER 
I don't know why this doesn't work.